# TypeError: Cannot read property "contentDetails" from undefined

Tags: google-apps-script

I am trying to get some youtube videos id from some playlists.  The loop starts but eventually I see the error in the subject line (at this line: var videoID = jsonVideoListResult.items[j].contentDetails.videoId;).

The Logger results are below too.  I am new to GAS so thank you for your help!

```
[17-05-05 20:39:33:921 EDT] VideoListResult: [object Object]
[17-05-05 20:39:33:922 EDT] VideoID: _R-mvxYzOo8
[17-05-05 20:39:33:982 EDT] VideoListResult: [object Object]
[17-05-05 20:39:33:983 EDT] VideoID: -oqQxOv9HHM
[17-05-05 20:39:34:037 EDT] VideoListResult: [object Object]
[17-05-05 20:39:34:037 EDT] VideoID: WV_I9rvrzsY
[17-05-05 20:39:34:077 EDT] VideoListResult: [object Object]


//get each playlist in the array and get its video ids
  var videoIdArray = [];
  for (var j=0; j<playlists.length; j++) {

  var videoURLprefix = 'https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems?part=contentDetails&maxResults=50&playlistId=';
  var videoURLsuffix = '&fields=items%2FcontentDetails%2FvideoId&key=';
  var playListID = String;
      playListID = playlists[j];
      //Logger.log(playListID);

  var getVideo = UrlFetchApp.fetch(videoURLprefix + playListID + videoURLsuffix + apiKey);

  var jsonVideoListResult = [];
      jsonVideoListResult = JSON.parse(getVideo);
    Logger.log("VideoListResult: " + jsonVideoListResult);
  var videoID = jsonVideoListResult.items[j].contentDetails.videoId;
  Logger.log("VideoID: " + videoID);
  videoIdArray.push(videoID); 

  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The length of items returned by the api call is different from the playlist length. Hence this code will need to have two loops. One for your playlist array second for the items array (which contains the list of videos in that particular playlist) returned by the api call.

Like so

```
var videoIdArray = [];
  for (var j=0; j<playlists.length; j++) {    //First Loop to go through each playlist

  var videoURLprefix = 'https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems?part=contentDetails&maxResults=50&playlistId=';
  var videoURLsuffix = '&fields=items%2FcontentDetails%2FvideoId&key=';
  var playListID = String;
      playListID = playlists[j];
      //Logger.log(playListID);

  var getVideo = UrlFetchApp.fetch(videoURLprefix + playListID + videoURLsuffix + apiKey);

  var jsonVideoListResult = [];
      jsonVideoListResult = JSON.parse(getVideo);
    Logger.log("VideoListResult: " + jsonVideoListResult);
  for (var i = 0 ; i< jsonVideoListResult.items.length ; i++) {   // Second loop to ireate through the each video in the playlist as returned by the api. 
   var videoID = jsonVideoListResult.items[i].contentDetails.videoId;
   Logger.log("VideoID: " + videoID);
   videoIdArray.push(videoID); 
 }

 }
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Ah!  This does.  Thank you, much!